# flash debug: flex app compiled with eclipse fdt doesn't show line numbers on errors

Tags: flash, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, fdt

I have firefox 3.6.15 with flash debug version 10.3. 
whenever an error occurs a popups comes up with the error and a stack trace but it does not line numbers of each leaf in the stack trace which makes it more difficult to debug.

any ideas how to configure it to actually show line numbers ?

I think it may relate to how I compile my flash application. (i think!) 
i use eclipse FDT 4.2 to compile and i added the following compiler flags:

```
-debug=true
-compiler.verbose-stacktraces
```

i think these parameters should be enough but I may be wrong.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is a limitation on the compiler.  Sometimes you will get errors without line numbers either because the error comes from a SWC (which mean the code is already compiled) or that your error relates to something that it's hard to get the line number (like a css syntax error for instance).

The good news is, Adobe is currently reworking the compiler and should be better in coming versions of Flex.

Comment: hi. thanks for the info but i think and hope this is not the case. i never get line numbers even on simple errors like using an object which is null. you wrote that when the code is already compiled i can't see line numbers like with swc usage so maybe i compile the flex application wrong in some sort of way.

Comment: I can't really help you without seeing the project and how you're doing it all.  Is it connecting to the FDT debugger property?  Can you use breakpoints?

Comment: i don't use the fdt debugger at all. i just use fdt for the editor, compile with flex 4.1 and open it with my browser.

Comment: and why not?!  I don't think you can get line numbers without the debugger.... I may be wrong, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: when i use 'Debug' to compile, it does show error numbers and i started using the debugger and it works great! i did not need to add any of the directives i showed above. all i needed to do is to compile with 'Debug'.